# Show comments below posts ASP.net Webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I am building a website where there will be posts and their respective comments.

The way I am displaying posts is I am looping through the records and putting them into a div. In addition I have another query to fetch data from comments table which gives me only related comments to the clicked post.

The problem is that when I am showing comments in a separate div (just beneath posts div on same level) using a foreach loop, comments are being displayed under all other posts. I tried using $(this`enter code here`).sibling and `$(this).children()` etc but it doesn't work.

In jquery I am hiding the comment div on document.ready and showing on click of the post.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
@foreach(var row in selectposts)
{
  <div id ="posts">@row.posts</div>
  @foreach(var row in selectcomments)
  {
  <div id ="comment">@row.comments</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are outputting all posts at one in `<div id ="posts">@row.posts</div>` , you probably need to loop over this first

Comment: posts are being looped over and the div id posts is outputting different posts on the page. The problem is I just want to show all relevant comment below the post and hence using another loop. but this is somehow showing comment from first post for all other posts. Hope this explains the scenario. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am not a Razor expert, but it looks like your code should work. It may have to do with you hiding/showing using jQuery. Did you try to output the page without jquery to see if it is outputted correctly beneath the related post?

Comment: It shows the comment under all other posts because it is executing the second for loop for all available posts. You are correct this has something to do with jquery but I tried $(this), $(this).children and $(this).siblings to show relevant comments but unfortunately no gain. Thanks.

Comment: If you can post your jquery code, that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
    var postsQuery = "SELECT * FROM Posts";
    var commentsQuery = "SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE PostId = @0";
}

@foreach(var post in db.Query(postsQuery)){
    <div class="post@post.Id">@post.PostContent</div>
    @foreach(var comment in db.Query(commentsQuery, post.Id)){
        <div class="comment@comment.Id">@comment.CommentContent</div>
    }
}
```

I have just typed this directly into SO, but it should be somewhere near.

jQuery is working as expected in your OP as you are using the same div ID throughout. In this example each post div will have a unique Id (e.g. post127) so they can be referenced individually by jQuery.